# How do you disable a specific warning for C++ in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I've found answers which suggest right clicking the solution and going to `Code Analysis Settings` but this has been deprecated in VS2019. I found a response here on StackOverflow that talked about Roslyn Analyzers, but that only applies to .NET. I need to disable warning `C26451` as it's completely useless and underlines every line where an arithmetic operation is performed on an `int`.

How do I disable this warning and can it be disabled permanently or just per solution?

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2019)? You can disable the warning on a per-project basis, not for the whole solution.

Comment: @CoryKramer Unfortunately the documentation is out of date. Right clicking the project does present a View submenu but that menu only contains the option `View Class Diagram`

Comment: I get the same although I am not at the latest update to 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable a specific warning for a C++ project, choose *Project* - *Properties* - *Configuration Properties* - *C/C++* - *Advanced* - *Disable Specific Warnings* - *Edit...* and then input warning code(s) you want to suppress (`26451` in your case) without the `C` part.
[image: Disabling warnings]

Performing code analysis now does not yield a `C26451` warning. That being said, suppressing warnings is best avoided.

Comment: I agree with you about suppressing warnings, but in this particular instance I find casting all my `int`s to `long`s more onerous.

Comment: Does this not remove the underlines from intellisense as well?

Comment: @Legion It does.